# find similar points in two matrices of different sizes

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrices: A(9672*3) with c1=X, c2=Y, c3=mass. Matrix B (3352*2) with c1=X and c2=Y.

I want to find within A the 3352 points of B, and extract their masses. I tried 'eq' but I need to have two matrices of same size.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
set_of_masses = A( ismember( A(:,1:2), B, 'rows'), 3 )
```

As long as each coordinate in B can also be found in A, then I think set_of_masses will correspond directly to the elements of B.

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly the function I was looking for !